# Remove all event listeners on a DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

Is it possible to remove all event listeners on an object even those declared externally, I have the following code at http://jsfiddle.net/E5n7g.

I use the built-in

```
addEventListener()
```

to add an event on the "a tag", I then try and remove this using jQuery, however it seems jQuery can only unbind events its bound itself.

The reason I am asking this, is because I am trying to use jQuery on combination with a product which uses Dojo.  When I bind the "click" event, its added to the list of event handlers however whenever I click that link its erasing that event handler and only leaving Dojo's intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I found that I used (and worked rather well) was the [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) function.

```
var new_el = el.cloneNode(true); //true means a deep copy
el.parentNode.replaceChild(new_el,el);
```

When you clone the element, it does not clone any events.

Comment: will the preventDefault(), stopPropagation() and unbind() will work for this requirement?

Comment: @jesse well, preventing the event would stop it, but it wouldn't unbind it. unbind can only work for bound events jQuery attaches, not DOM events.

Comment: yeah, I see, removeEventListener can clear the event listen, and the parameter must be similar with the addEventListener. **url:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/E5n7g/2/

Comment: Note that this has the side effect of invalidating all references you hold to the DOM element.